# Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, exception, magento

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /bitnami/magento/app/code/Apptha/Marketplace/Block/Assignproduct/Manage.php on line 224

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /bitnami/magento/app/code/Apptha/Marketplace/Block/Assignproduct/Manage.php on line 224

#1 count() called at [app/code/Apptha/Marketplace/Block/Assignproduct/Manage.php:224]
#2 Apptha\Marketplace\Block\Assignproduct\Manage->getFilterAssignProducts() called at [app/code/Apptha/Marketplace/Block/Assignproduct/Manage.php:75]

Comment: This means your extension `Apptha_Marketplace` is not compatible with PHP7.2. Install an updated version if exists. Otherwise, you need to update it yourself. Or you can copy paste the offending line here so others can help you find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of in PHP 7.2 NULL in count() return Warning. and you can try to change on line 224 count variable as below. and Be careful.. If $variable is already an array it will be [[$variable]] and count will be 1

```
count(array($variable));
```